# JMX connection to Gemfire over SSL

Tags: ssl, jmx, gemfire

I have used GFSH to start locator like below

```
start locator --name=gemfire_locator --security-properties-file="../config/gfsecurity.properties" --J=-Dgemfire.ssl-enabled-components=all --mcast-port=0 --J=-Dgemfire.jmx-manager-ssl=true
```

Also started server

```
start server --name=server1 --security-properties-file="../config/gfsecurity.properties" --J=-Dgemfire.ssl-enabled-components=all --mcast-port=0 --J=-Dgemfire.jmx-manager-ssl=true
```

I am trying to connect to Gemfire as ClientCache which works perfectly fine over SSL. But When I connect as JMX client, I am getting below error in Java code as well as Jconsole.

```
Error: 
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectIOException: non-JRMP server at remote endpoint]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:369)
    at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:270)
    at SamplePlugin.main(SamplePlugin.java:101)
```

Am I missing any other configuration?

Here is my `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=true
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=myhostname
```

Comment: You probably also need to set trust/keystore values for the client you're connecting with: `javax.net.ssl.keyStore`, `javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword`, `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` and `javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword`.

Comment: In GFSH >> start jconsole --J=-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=../cert/trusted.keystore --J=-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password --J=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=../cert/trusted.keystore --J=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password  
  

Still same error

Answer (score 1):

You will also need to add the `geode-core` jar to your classpath for jvisualvm. Use the `--cp:a` option. I would suggest just using `geode-dependencies.jar` as that will get everything you might need.

The reason this is required is explained a bit in the comments for [ContextAwareSSLRMIClientSocketFactory](https://github.com/apache/geode/blob/develop/geode-core/src/main/java/org/apache/geode/management/internal/ContextAwareSSLRMIClientSocketFactory.java). Basically it seems that when RMI uses SSL, the necessary `RMIClientSocketFactory` is exported from the ***server*** to the client for use there. In general this would simply just be `SslRMIClientSocketFactory`. But in our case, we have a custom socket factory and so the client (jvisualvm in this case) needs to have access to it.

Comment: @Mya please could you respond whether this worked for you. Thanks!